# Lucene find co-occurence list

Tags: java, lucene

I have a Lucene index of a big text file (corpus), for some of n-grams I need to find a list of similar words (co-occurrence list).

For example, I have unigram - "table" with term frequency 1500 and I need to get such a co-occurrence list, with co-occurrence counts and the measured
co-occurrence strength:

```
WORD       FREQ         Dice(Jaccard) coefficient
brown      1286         0.3
break      729          0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serach for `brown` and `break`.

Lucene will only return documents that contain both, if your set the parameters right.